# Laravel Socialite (VK) - InvalidStateException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Люди добрые!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, используем на проекте Socialite с провайдером ВКонтакте, на **production**, если пользователь не авторизован через ВКонтакте на момент входа на сайте, падает Exception (InvalidStateException), но в итоге авторизация проходит

Лог: https://pastebin.com/nZGDaVkc

Ничего не помогает, на локалке не можем смоделировать ситуацию

Уже и SESSION_DOMAIN копали, и обновляли кеш приложения, конфигов, танцевали с бубнами, но ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, проблема была в том, что после успешной авторизации пользователя редиректили таким образом:

```
return back();
```

Исправили на

```
return redirect('/');
```

И после этого все заработало